# Treat Null value as zero

Tags: influxdb

I have a query to influxdb, something like:

```
SELECT last("Shop1.balance")+last("Shop2.balance")+last("Shop2.balance") + last("Shop2.balance") FROM "balances" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(previous)
```

where i am receiving with graphana a total balance for all shops . It works fine until I add a new shop with a new data: a new shop balance can be null for some interval in history and whole calculated value will be null. I can not reorganize my database but may be I can change my query to receive date where null interval will be treated as zero in a total sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works as you've asked:

```
SELECT last("Shop1.balance") + last("Shop2.balance") + last("Shop3.balance)
FROM "balances" 
WHERE $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(0)
```

---

**Demo**

```
select last(balance1) as last_balance_1, last(balance2) as last_balance_2 
from balance 
where time > '2018-03-07T10:44:14.0000000Z' and time < '2018-03-07T10:44:52.0000000Z' 
group by time(7s)
```

Result:

```
name: balance
time                 last_balance_1 last_balance_2
----                 -------------- --------------
2018-03-07T10:44:13Z 1              2
2018-03-07T10:44:20Z 2              3
2018-03-07T10:44:27Z 4
2018-03-07T10:44:34Z 5              6
2018-03-07T10:44:41Z 7
2018-03-07T10:44:48Z 8              9
```

---

```
select last(balance1) as last_balance_1, last(balance2) as last_balance_2 
from balance 
where time > '2018-03-07T10:44:14.0000000Z' and time < '2018-03-07T10:44:52.0000000Z' 
group by time(7s) fill(0)
```

Result:

```
name: balance
time                 last_balance_1 last_balance_2
----                 -------------- --------------
2018-03-07T10:44:13Z 1              2
2018-03-07T10:44:20Z 2              3
2018-03-07T10:44:27Z 4              0
2018-03-07T10:44:34Z 5              6
2018-03-07T10:44:41Z 7              0
2018-03-07T10:44:48Z 8              9
```